# Possible to use HTML tabindex to trigger a function

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, cordova, tabindex

I'm developing an app in phonegap, and I have a complex form that has a text input at the top, then several buttons below it, then more text inputs below them.

My questions is: Is it possible to trigger a function such as a button click through the tab index.

And it would have to be through the tabindex because iphones have a 'next' button, and I would want the function to be triggered when that is clicked.

Comment: Have you tried the *focus* event?

Comment: Neal, I don't know how to bring it up, but would be grateful for you insight. RobG, the butttons can't be focused, so I'm beginning to think there is no way.

Comment: Ok nevermind Neal, I found what it means, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 9) {
        yourFunction();
     }
});
```